# Checkbox doesn't work on bootstrap modal using a partial view on a .net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I'm developing on a bootstrap-modal over a partial view (.net core) and want to use some checkbox to complete my formulary but when giving click the checkbox doesn't change. It seems to be frozen

I'm using VS 2017, C#, .net core and IIS v10

```
<!-- enter code here--> 
@model Acre.Business.DTOs.FormMetadataDTO

@section head {

    <link href="~/Content/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/summernote/plugin/databasic/summernote-ext-databasic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="editLabel">Agregar <small>Metadatos</small></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
    <div class="form">
        <div class="form-body">
            <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="FormMetadata" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="FormMetadataMTE" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide" id="ErrorMessage1">
                        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> Hay algunos errores en el formulario. Por favor verifique a continuación.
                    </div>

                    @*DUPLICADO*@
                    @*<div class="alert alert-danger display-hide" id="ErrorDuplicado" style="@(@ViewBag.StyleErrorMessage); display:@ViewBag.Display">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> @ViewBag.ErrorDuplicado
                        </div>*@

                    <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide" id="ErrorMessage2" style="@(@ViewBag.StyleErrorMessage)">
                        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
                        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> ¡La validación del formulario es exitosa!
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                @*<label asp-for="TipoFormularioId" class="control-label col-md-4 text-right"></label>*@
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoFormularioId, "TipoFormularioId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 text-right" })
                                <div class="col-xs-7">
                                    <select asp-for="TipoFormularioId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TipoFormularioId"></select>
                                    @*@Html.DropDownList("TipoFormularioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", disabled= "disabled" })*@
                                    <div class="form-control-focus"></div>
                                    <span class="help-block">Seleccione el tipo de formulario</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                <label asp-for="MetaCampoId" class="control-label col-md-4 text-right"></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-7">
                                    <select asp-for="MetaCampoId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MetaCampoId" id="MetaCampoId"></select>
                                    <div class="form-control-focus"></div>
                                    <span class="help-block">Seleccione el metacampo</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @*<div class="col-xs-6">
                                <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                    <label asp-for="TipoFormularioId" class="control-label col-md-4 text-right"></label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                                        <select asp-for="TipoFormularioId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TipoFormularioId"></select>
                                        <div class="form-control-focus"></div>
                                        <span class="help-block">Seleccione el tipo de formulario</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>*@

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                <label asp-for="MetaEtiqueta" class="control-label col-md-4 text-right"></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-7">
                                    <input asp-for="MetaEtiqueta" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <div class="form-control-focus"></div>
                                    <span class="help-block">Escriba MetaEtiqueta</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                <label asp-for="Orden" class="control-label col-md-4 text-right"></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-7">
                                    <input asp-for="Orden" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <div class="form-control-focus"></div>
                                    <span class="help-block">Escriba Orden</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requerido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="md-checkbox-list">
                                        <div class="md-checkbox">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Requerido, new { @class = "md-check" })
                                            <label class="col-md-1 md-checkbox md-checkbox-outline text-right" for="Requerido">
                                                <span class="inc"></span>
                                                <span class="check"></span>
                                                <span class="box"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VisibleEnGrid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="md-checkbox-list">
                                        <div class="md-checkbox">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.VisibleEnGrid, new { @class = "md-check" })
                                            <label class="col-md-1 md-checkbox md-checkbox-outline text-right" for="VisibleEnGrid">
                                                <span class="inc"></span>
                                                <span class="check"></span>
                                                <span class="box"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Privado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="md-checkbox-list">
                                        <div class="md-checkbox">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Privado, new { @class = "md-check" })
                                            <label class="col-md-1 md-checkbox md-checkbox-outline text-right" for="Privado">
                                                <span class="inc"></span>
                                                <span class="check"></span>
                                                <span class="box"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                <label asp-for="Ayuda" class="control-label col-md-2 text-right"></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-9">
                                    <input asp-for="Ayuda" class="form-control Editor" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <div class="form-control-focus"></div>
                                    <span class="help-block">Escriba Ayuda</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-5">
                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "Index", "FormMetadata", null, new { @class = "btn red" })*@
                            @*<a href="@TempData["Refer"]" class="btn red">Cancelar</a>*@
                            <button type="button" class="btn red" id="crudCancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn blue" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>     <!-- END FORM-->
</div>
@*<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="btnGuardar">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Guardar
        </button>
    </div>*@

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script src="~/Content/summernote/summernote.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/summernote/plugin/databasic/summernote-ext-databasic.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/summernote/plugin/hello/summernote-ext-hello.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/summernote/lang/summernote-es-ES.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/summernote/plugin/specialchars/summernote-ext-specialchars.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/home-index.js"></script>

}
```

I expect that my checkbox change of state when I give click over it

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue , could you please show more details ?

Comment: I changed the previous source code. That's all the code of my partial view